# How do I use query-parameters outside ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a ui-router-based Angular app, and I want to maintain some state which has nothing to do with routing.

So let's say the URL is `#/profile?color=green`.  That means the state is "profile" and the color of the app should be green.  If the URL changes to `#/profile?color=red`, nothing about the state or ng-view or the controller associated with the current route changes, but an entirely separate bit of code should be notified (and it will change the class of the body tag).  That same parameter is available on every possible state; it's orthogonal to the state.

I could just watch `$location` and parse everything myself, but I am wondering if some facility of ui-router or $state or something would make this easier.

(By the way, to anyone who plans to explain why I don't want to do what I want to do, no, in fact, I do want to do what I want to do, so thanks-kay-bye.)

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely accomplish what you're trying to do with `$location`. I would probably use **$stateChangeStart** so that you can do less parsing on you're end to accomplish what you're looking for:

```
$rootScope.$on('stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams) {
  if (toParams.color === 'red') {
    //etc
  }
}
```

The great part about this solution is that you can listen for these params in this way across any **toState** which satisfies your requirement that this param is applicable regardless of state.

**[stateChangeStart documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events)**

Comment: To get stateChangeStart to work I would have to mark every single state as taking "color" as parameter (the app has 43 different states!), and whenever color changes, the ng-view would reload, which is suboptimal.

Comment: I see...yeah you're right then $location might be your best bet.